# How to find Microsoft Windows Installer version number?

Tags: windows, windows-installer

I'm trying to figure out if I need to upgrade to [Windows Installer 4.5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=5A58B56F-60B6-4412-95B9-54D056D6F9F4&displaylang=en), but I don't know how to check the current version number.

What is the procedure to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `msiexec /?` on the command line and it will give you the version.

Unless you've got a good reason to (read: an application requires it), I wouldn't bother personally.